# R cor() returns asymmetric results

Tags: r, correlation, symmetric

correlation between A and B or B and A should be same. 
However, when I use cor() function in R, it returns asymmetric results. 
Could anyone explain why it happen?

```
set.seed(123)

mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100),10)
```

> ```
>          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]       [,8]         [,9]      [,10]
>
> [1,] -0.56047565 1.2240818 -1.0678237 0.42646422 -0.69470698 0.25331851 0.37963948 -0.4910312 0.005764186 0.9935039
>
> [2,] -0.23017749 0.3598138 -0.2179749 -0.29507148 -0.20791728 -0.02854676 -0.50232345 -2.3091689 0.385280401 0.5483970
>
> [3,] 1.55870831 0.4007715 -1.0260044 0.89512566 -1.26539635 -0.04287046 -0.33320738 1.0057385 -0.370660032 0.2387317
>
> [4,] 0.07050839 0.1106827 -0.7288912 0.87813349 2.16895597 1.36860228 -1.01857538 -0.7092008 0.644376549 -0.6279061
>
> [5,] 0.12928774 -0.5558411 -0.6250393 0.82158108 1.20796200 -0.22577099 -1.07179123 -0.6880086 -0.220486562 1.3606524
>
> [6,] 1.71506499 1.7869131 -1.6866933 0.68864025 -1.12310858 1.51647060 0.30352864 1.0255714 0.331781964 -0.6002596
>
> [7,] 0.46091621 0.4978505 0.8377870 0.55391765 -0.40288484 -1.54875280 0.44820978 -0.2847730 1.096839013 2.1873330
>
> [8,] -1.26506123 -1.9666172 0.1533731 -0.06191171 -0.46665535 0.58461375 0.05300423 -1.2207177 0.435181491 1.5326106
>
> [9,] -0.68685285 0.7013559 -1.1381369 -0.30596266 0.77996512 0.12385424 0.92226747 0.1813035 -0.325931586 -0.2357004
>
> [10,] -0.44566197 -0.4727914 1.2538149 -0.38047100 -0.08336907 0.21594157 2.05008469 -0.1388914 1.148807618 -1.0264209
> ```

```
mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(100),10)
```

> ```
>          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       [,10]
>
> [1,] -0.71040656 -0.57534696 0.11764660 1.44455086 0.7017843 0.7877388 1.0527115 -0.21538051 -1.06332613 0.21444531
>
> [2,] 0.25688371 0.60796432 -0.94747461 0.45150405 -0.2621975 0.7690422 -1.0491770 0.06529303 1.26318518 -0.32468591
>
> [3,] -0.24669188 -1.61788271 -0.49055744 0.04123292 -1.5721442 0.3322026 -1.2601552 -0.03406725 -0.34965039 0.09458353
>
> [4,] -0.34754260 -0.05556197 -0.25609219 -0.42249683 -1.5146677 -1.0083766 3.2410399 2.12845190 -0.86551286 -0.89536336
>
> [5,] -0.95161857 0.51940720 1.84386201 -2.05324722 -1.6015362 -0.1194526 -0.4168576 -0.74133610 -0.23627957 -1.31080153
>
> [6,] -0.04502772 0.30115336 -0.65194990 1.13133721 -0.5309065 -0.2803953 0.2982276 -1.09599627 -0.19717589 1.99721338
>
> [7,] -0.78490447 0.10567619 0.23538657 -1.46064007 -1.4617556 0.5629895 0.6365697 0.03778840 1.10992029 0.60070882
>
> [8,] -1.66794194 -0.64070601 0.07796085 0.73994751 0.6879168 -0.3724388 -0.4837806 0.31048075 0.08473729 -1.25127136
>
> [9,] -0.38022652 -0.84970435 -0.96185663 1.90910357 2.1001089 0.9769734 0.5168620 0.43652348 0.75405379 -0.61116592
>
> [10,] 0.91899661 -1.02412879 -0.07130809 -1.44389316 -1.2870305 -0.3745809 0.3689645 -0.45836533 -0.49929202 -1.18548008
> ```

```
cor(mat1, mat2)
```

> ```
>          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]         [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]         [,10]
>
> [1,] 0.26831285 0.06053092 -0.10428649 -0.1301460 -0.554848654 -0.09595799 -0.13256217 -0.30476987 -0.08171084 0.7086072147
>
> [2,] 0.38655947 0.14373593 -0.40388246 0.3835567 0.075479342 0.40039530 0.19889156 -0.21208747 -0.02053028 0.8090298626
>
> [3,] 0.14732272 -0.05669277 0.21555988 -0.6152566 -0.301214438 -0.12702958 -0.05972158 0.02785521 0.26717189 -0.4338816437
>
> [4,] -0.30093369 0.14383049 0.39888825 -0.2746142 -0.582382672 -0.32407734 0.24484167 0.06457118 -0.43777818 0.3442870182
>
> [5,] -0.06016582 0.29980935 0.28556414 -0.3015196 -0.088257857 -0.37695193 0.61224534 0.63156860 -0.11296668 -0.5972797414
>
> [6,] 0.14041298 0.00369509 -0.30192170 0.4326353 0.146180544 -0.58680476 0.36100019 0.20061423 -0.55264160 0.0948611180
>
> [7,] 0.44131857 -0.46410860 -0.29527564 0.1254691 0.305840886 0.19688262 -0.02613450 -0.32273399 0.04854920 0.0771804101
>
> [8,] 0.15644962 -0.48583862 -0.11654567 0.1112339 -0.111546629 -0.05705737 0.03819937 -0.29408586 -0.33312057 0.5133571634
>
> [9,] 0.28462219 0.20184029 -0.02527392 -0.4430365 -0.365796993 -0.38339974 0.34573814 0.13526609 0.12030810 0.0007793646
>
> [10,] -0.74697187 0.26225544 0.50764178 -0.2074576 0.001937912 0.34793935 -0.30279688 -0.13584016 0.36224565 -0.0439142755
> ```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Why should the correlation between the first column of mat1 and the second column of mat2 be the same as the correlation between the second column of mat1 and the first column of mat2?

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I was fooled :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's be clear about what's happening when you pass matrices into `cor`. It's true that `cor` is symmetric when passing in simple vectors.

```
cor(mat1[,1], mat2[,1])
# [1] 0.2683129
cor(mat2[,1], mat1[,1])
# [1] 0.2683129
```

But when you pass in matrices, For each `i`, `j` position in the resulting matrix you are getting

```
cor(mat1, mat2)
 -> result[i, j] = cor(mat1[,i], mat2[,j])
cor(mat2, mat1)
 -> result[i, j] = cor(mat2[,i], mat1[,j])
```

Note that the values in the matrix are different because the columns are compared in a different order. Note that if you just transpose one of the matrices, they will match

```
all(cor(mat1, mat2) == t(cor(mat2, mat1)))
# [1] TRUE
```

So one should not expect the results to be identical when switching parameter order with matrices because the results are determined by the column ordering.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much for your clear explanation!!